# PHP/MySQL: Insert rows temporarily

Tags: php, mysql, rows, temporary

I am working on a complex database application written with PHP and Mysqli. For large database operations I´m using daemons (also PHP) working in the background. During these operations which may take several minutes I want to prevent the users from accesing the data being affected and show them a message instead.

I thought about creating a Mysql table and insert a row each time a specific daemon operation takes place. Then I would be always able to check if a certain operation takes place while trying to access the data.

However, of course it is important that the records do not stay in the database, if the daemon process gets terminated by any reason (kill from console, losing database connection, pulling the plug, etc.) I do not think that Mysql transactions / rollbacks are able do this, because a commit is necessary in order to make the changes public and the records will remain in the database if terminated.

Is there a way to ensure that the records get deleted if the process gets terminated?

Comment: Are all your daemons hosted on one server?

Comment: Yes, everything is hosted on one server right now. But I will move the database to a seperate server when the application goes public.

Comment: Well, if all your daemons are on one server, regardless of the server of the database, you could simply update a file and write the time of the update. Check whether the timestamp saved in the file is less than 10 seconds old, and, if it is, do not allow any actions. That way, you should simply update that file from within your daemon while it is running, and even if it is terminated in an unorthodox manner, it won't affect your later processing.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea. It could be also done using the database. Update timestamp every x seconds and delete if nothing happened for a while. However, I would appreciate more suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, I actually implemented it for a University course a few years ago.

The trick I used is to play with the transaction isolation. If your daemons create the record indicating they are in progress, but do not commit it, then you are correct in saying that the other clients will not see that record. But, if you set the isolation level for that client to READ UNCOMMITTED, you will see the record saying it's in progress - since READ UNCOMMITTED will show you the changes from other clients which are not yet committed. (The daemon would be left with the default isolation level).

You should set the client's isolation level to read uncommitted for that daemon check only, not for it's other work as it could be very dangerous.

If the daemon crashes, the transaction gets aborted and the record goes. If it's successful, it can either mark it done in the db or delete the record etc, and then it commits.
This is really nice, since if the daemon fails for any reason all the changes it made are reversed and it can be retried.

If you need more explanation or code I may be able to find my assignment somewhere :)

[Transaction isolation levels reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynindex-isolevel.html)

Note that this all requires InnoDB or any good transactional DB.

Comment: That looks interesting. I will give it a try :)

Comment: Works very well, thank you. Here is a short example of using transaction isolation to ensure my daemon can´t be executed multiple times at once.

Comment: I´m not allowed to post it right now. I will post it later ;)

Comment: One further question: Is it possible to use one connection for different transactions at the same time or do I have to build a second connection in order to commit my other queries? (without committing the progress indicator on top of the script, which I want to roll back in any case). [Mysqli extension]

Comment: I don't believe you can use multiple transactions in one connection. But I don't think you want to in this case. INSERT the progress indicator as the first thing you do in your transaction, do your work in the transaction, and DELETE it as the last thing. That way, no matter whether the transaction is committed or not, the marker will never be persisted.

Comment: I'd actually recommend you don't delete them but instead just have a status field which gets marked as done, that way you keep a record of what has happened. But depends on the application whether you want that.